# Web scraping with another browser

Tags: vba, web-scraping

So I'm new to vba and i am try to get price which site is [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com). But i cant use steam because internet explorer doesnt open steam. (its opening but drawmenü not working, i cant sign in my account, the site isn't responding my clicks.) 2 days ago it was working well. but google chrome and edge works well they dont have problem.

**Not loading well:**
[image: Not loading well]

**When i click the sign in button its doing nothing.**
[image: a]

Some pages not loading
[image: Some pages not loading]

Draw menüs not opening, so i cant change language sorry for that its not english
[image: Draw menü]

i reinstall my internet explorer, i did format but its same. So i dont want to use internet explorer. What should i do, i cant use IE for scraping data.

There is my getting price code:

```
Sub SPrice1()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim itemEle As Object
Dim Des1 As String
Dim y As Integer
Dim x As Integer

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

y = 1
For x = 1 To 21
objIE.navigate "http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=578080#p" & x & "x_name_asc"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
MsgBox "Checking"

For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_row_link")
    Prc1 = itemEle.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(1).textContent
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & y).Value = Prc1
    y = y + 1
Next

Next x


objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Try out selenium, its an useful framework for web testing. You can also control your browser with it to automatise tasks!

Comment: is it a browser ? as i say i am new to vba . Can i use this code for selenium ? which line i have to change ?

Comment: Selenium can be used through vb.net and the code is not very different.

Comment: Are you sure IE couldn't do what you wanted to? You don't need to go for selenium. If IE failed you that means there is something wrong you did yourself. You could not make it a go successfully.

Comment: i deleted internet explorer extentions with iobit unistaller 3 -4 days ago but i format my pc and its not fixed. i tried everythings. Now i think, i have hdd and if i buy ssd and install new windows 10 in sdd. Can i have solve ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of scraping one link,using [Selenium Basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/),  which you can easily adapt into a loop. After installing you need to add a reference to Selenium Type Library.

---

**CSS Selectors:**

I use the CSS "."  - [className selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp).

So, `.market_listing_game_name` means get all the elements who className matches the string after the `"."`. Same principle applies for the others. The last selector is a chained selector of className `normal_price` within elements with a className of `market_table_value`.

---

**Example CSS selector (Sample of results):**

[image: CSS query]

---

**Example from page:**

[image: Example from page]

---

**Examples from code output:**

[image: Sample output]

***Note: These numbers are constantly fluctuating.***

---

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub GetInfoSel()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=578080#p1_name_asc"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get url

        Dim gameNames As Object, itemNames As Object, quantities As Object, normalPrices As Object

        Set gameNames = .findElementsbyCSS(".market_listing_game_name")
        Set itemNames = .findElementsbyCSS(".market_listing_item_name")
        Set quantities = .findElementsbyCSS(".market_listing_num_listings_qty")
        Set normalPrices = .findElementsbyCSS(".market_table_value .normal_price")

        Dim currentItem As Long
        For currentItem = 1 To gameNames.Count
            Debug.Print "Game: " & gameNames(currentItem).Text
            Debug.Print "Item: " & itemNames(currentItem).Text
            Debug.Print "Qty: " & quantities(currentItem).Text
            Debug.Print "Normal Price -  " & normalPrices(currentItem).Text
        Next currentItem
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

this task can be done very easily by using python beautifulsoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/